# not-unique tensor decomposition for lanet analysis

Tags: python, tensor, decomposition, tensorly

Want to use Tucker and canonical polyadic decomposition (cdp or PARAFAC/CANDECOMP) of 3-dimension tensor for latent analysis.

I use python, function from tensorly.decomposition.parafac of library tensorly.

```
from tensorly.decomposition import parafac
# Rank of the CP decomposition
cp_rank = 5
 Perform the CP decomposition
weights, factors = parafac(result, non_negative=True ,rank=cp_rank , normalize_factors=True, init='random', tol=10e-6)
# Reconstruct the tensor from the factors
cp_reconstruction = tl.kruskal_to_tensor((weights, factors))
```

Factors matrices and core are not-unique (can multiply on non-singular matrix), so factor matrices change after calling the function.

Use this code for understand this:

```
weights = 0
for i in range(100):
    error = weights
    weights, factors = parafac(result, non_negative=True ,rank=8, normalize_factors=True, init='random', tol=10e-6)
    
    error -= weights
    print(tl.norm(error))
```

How I can describe or analysis every components of tensor.Has ones any meaning?
For matrix I understand SVD decomposition. What do for tensor?

Answer (score 0):

The decomposition you are using in your example (parafac, also known as Canonical-Polyadic -CP- decomposition), does not have a core. It expresses the original tensor as a weighted sum of rank-1 tensors, i.e. a weighted sum of outer-product of vectors. These vectors are collected for each mode (dimension) into the factors matrices. The weights of the sum are a vector. The CP decomposition, unlike the Tucker, does not have a core and is unique under mild conditions (you could consider CP as a special case of Tucker, with the weight vector being the values of a diagonal core).

However, there are several issues with directly comparing the factors: for one, even if the decomposition is unique, it is also invariant under permutations of the factors so you can't directly compare the factors. In addition, finding the actual rank of a tensor is in general NP-hard. What is typically computed with a CP decomposition is a low-rank approximation (i.e. best rank-R approximation) which is also, in general, NP-hard and the ALS is just a (good) heuristic. If you want to compare several factorized tensors, it is easier to compare the reconstructions rather than directly the factors.

For latent factor analysis I advise you look at [this paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/v15/anandkumar14b.html) which shows how you can learn latent variable models by factorizing low-order observable moments.